# Numeric Captcha for PHP

Tags: php, numbers, captcha

### Is there a **numeric** captcha available for **PHP**?

(*which doesn't rely on JavaScript being turned on*)

---

EDIT:

- I know there are JS-independent
  captchas out there.
- I know there
  are PHP captchas out there.
- I know
  there are numeric captchas out there.

But I'm looking for a **PHP numeric Javascript-independent** captcha.
The only numeric captcha's I've found are either for ASP.NET or jQuery/JS based ones.
I don't want any of those as an answer to the question.

And I'm not taking about a small website here. In the answer I'd like to know whether your suggestion puts a lot of strain on the server or not.

Comment: There a lots of captcha-systems around the web. And it's not that hard to code one yourself. Are you familiar with php?

Comment: most captcha don't need javascript google it http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=php+captcha&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: Javascript is often only used for obfuscation in this context. If numbers are displayed as-is in a page, a specifically crafted spambot can read it out too easily. (Virtually none of the automated ones do.)

Comment: @faileN yes I'm very familiar with PHP. To save myself hassle I'd like to just use a pre-made one. If not I might try and take the code from the [Tips Tricks numeric ASP captcha](http://www.tipstricks.org/) and translate it. But still I've heard creating the images at runtime is very costly

Comment: You can try this: http://captchas.net/sample/php/ .

Comment: You can try this: http://captchas.net/sample/php/ .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I guess it can't be avoided to deal with rendering an image when dealing with captchas?
Here's a simple one (and may not be the most elegant):

[image: sample output]

```
session_start();

$strings = '123456789';
$i = 0;
$characters = 6;
$code = '';
while ($i < $characters)
{ 
    $code .= substr($strings, mt_rand(0, strlen($strings)-1), 1);
    $i++;
} 

$_SESSION['captcha'] = $code;

//generate image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(124, 40);
$foreground = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$shadow = imagecolorallocate($im, 173, 172, 168);
$background = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 200, 200, $background);

// use your own font!
$font = 'monofont.ttf';

//draw text:
imagettftext($im, 35, 0, 9, 28, $shadow, $font, $code);
imagettftext($im, 35, 0, 2, 32, $foreground, $font, $code);     

// prevent client side  caching
header("Expires: Wed, 1 Jan 1997 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

//send image to browser
header ("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Display it in a form:

```
<img src="captcha.php">
Enter the code above: <input type="text" name="captcha">
```

Once submitted, check the entered code:

```
if ($_POST['captcha'] == $_SESSION['captcha'])
    // do your thing
```

Comment: Thank you for the first proper answer. If I were to use this I guess I could set the shadow values randomly. But is this image generation costly? I'm not taking about a small website here.

Comment: @Adam, even big websites uses image captchas and they're not too worried about it being costly because they know their system can handle it.

Comment: @lbu This is why I used Stack Overflow. I'm looking for an answer to a specific non-trivial problem.

Comment: @tradyblix Then I guess the question is, can our system handle this extra load and if it can, will my boss be ok with the extra load. Hmm

Comment: @Adam, that I cannot answer, you need to deal with your `boss`. I provided an answer to `Is there a numeric captcha available for PHP?` and I believe you didn't mention any server load issues that may cause you and your `boss`.

Comment: the example is not load intensive but easy to crack, any captcha you implement will add more code meaning more load unless you outsource but then you still have to echo it out. i had a play with the example and added lots of random stuff using imagearc() in a loop :)

Comment: @Lawrence Thanks! Easy to crack? Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

CAPTCHA's dont necessarily rely on javascript (I think your thinking of reCATCHA), a stand alone image is all you need.

http://www.phpcaptcha.org/

At it's most simple, a numeric CAPTCHA would work like...

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['code'])) {
    if ($_POST['code'] == $_SESSION['captcha']) {
        echo "Captcha valid";
    }
    else {
        echo "Captcha NOT valid";
    }
}

$_SESSION['captcha'] = mt_rand(10000, 99999);
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <p>Enter this number: <?php echo $_SESSION['captcha']; ?></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="code" /> <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: No. I'm not thinking of reCAPTCHA.

Comment: @fire can this provide a numeric captcha?

Comment: reCATCHA can be used without javascript too

Comment: That is way to easy to bypass. If I wanted to steal your content or spam your site, you're making it easy for me. You can't hardcode the captcha like that

Comment: preg_match('#number: (.*)<\/p>#'); :p

Answer (score 1):

May be you have also thought about a [figlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figlet) captcha. This saves lots of time, because you don't need images to be rendered. In my homepage I am using this kind of captcha. You may take a look at [this page](http://failen.com/blog/usability-im-login-und-sign-up) (scroll to the bottom, you can't oversee it ;)). I've implemented it via Zend-Framework. Better said with [Zend_Captcha_Figlet](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.captcha.adapters.html).

However I think it's hard to implement if you are not using Zend_Form. But I think it's quite a nice solution.

*EDIT*

Another solution would be a blind-captcha. It's very easy to implement and works great (had good experience with that for a long time). It works like this:

- In your form provide an input-field with an empty value.
- Hide it initially via css (this should not be done with inline-styles)
- in your form-validation (php) check if this field contains a value. if so it's probably a spambot who filled out each and every input-field.
- A user won't fill it, because he doesn't see it (of course he will see it, if he has disabled css in his browser)

Easy, but effective.

Comment: I like this idea but I read somewhere (can't seem to find the post now) that this is easy to bypass. Is this true?

Comment: I can only speak for myself. I've haven't been spammed with this captcha active. I'm sure it can be bypassed, but I can't imagine, that this is easy. Or let's say most spambot-developers concentrate on trying to bypass images and not on figlet. So there is a smaller chance, that a spambot even understands, what you are doing..

Comment: I've also provided another captcha-possibility. See my answer above

Comment: The problem is that with our site we're not protecting against spam (it is not community driven). So we won't really be able to test it like you've been able to ("I've haven't been spammed"). With our type of business, people would actively set out to scrape our content, so if they realise we've put up a request-limit & captcha, then they will look at it and try bypass it/work around it. So, I'll need to find out if figlet's are secure enough I guess. Hopefully that information is online and I don't have to test it

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://www.captcha.ru/kcaptcha/ Default this library generate key with alphabet symbols, but you can change config file(set new value for variable $allowed_symbols = "0123456789" as example) for generating only numeric keys.

Answer (score 0):

Don't go for any other php files for adding numerical captcha in your form.Just try the following

```
    <input id="num1" type="text" name="num1" value="<?php echo rand(1,4); ?>" readonly="readonly" /> +
<input id="num2" type="text" name="num2" value="<?php echo rand(5,9); ?>" readonly="readonly" /> =
<input id="captcha" class="captcha" type="text" onblur="check_captcha(this.value);" maxlength="2" />
```

and in the function you can validate easily

```
<script>
function check_captcha(res)
{
if(res)
{
var val=parseInt($('#num1').val())+parseInt($('#num2').val());
if(val!=res)
{
alert('Incorrect value, please try again');
$('#captcha').val('');
$('#captcha').focus();
}
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: I can't understand, is this trolling or a solution someone uses?

Comment: Yes i used for my form

Comment: I'm sorry for your company then, it's completely unsecure

Comment: using variable in the client side is not safe and is dangerous

Answer (score 0):

Just open any captcha php file and remove letters from the string which generates captcha word