# Contact form with math captcha

Tags: php

I've successfully created a contact form with php that gives the various required messages.    Now I would like to add a simple random arithmetic captcha (non-image).  See the anonymised (working) html form and existing (working, but without arithmetic captcha) php below.

The idea is to show "Incorrect answer" in the same way as the other error messages, or to pass to the Thankyou page for a correctly filled out form with correct answer.  I've had a good go at this but can't quite get it to work.  Any assistance much appreciated.

---

HTML:

```
    <p>Area of interest:
    <input type="radio" name="likeit" value="A" checked="checked" /> A
    <input type="radio" name="likeit" value="B" /> B
    <input type="radio" name="likeit" value="C" /> C</p>

    <p>How did you hear about us?
    <select name="how">
    <option value=""> -- Please select -- </option>
    <option>Recommendation</option>
    <option>Internet</option>
    <option>Advertisement</option>
    <option>Other</option>
    </select></p>

    <p><strong>Your message subject:</strong><br /><input type="text" name="subject" size="35"/></p>

    <p><strong>Your message:</strong><br />
    <textarea name="comments" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea></p>

    <p>Please answer the following arithmetic question: What is <?php echo $digit1;?> + <?php echo $digit2;?>?
     <input name="captcha" type="text" size="2" id="captcha"/></p>


    <p><input type="submit" value="Send" /></p>

    </form>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
    /* Contact form with arithmetic captcha */
    $myemail  = "enquiries@X.co.uk";

    /* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
    $yourname = check_input($_POST['yourname'], "Enter your name");
    $email    = check_input($_POST['email']);
    $telephone  = check_input($_POST['telephone']);
    $website  = check_input($_POST['website']);
    $likeit   = check_input($_POST['likeit']);
    $how_find = check_input($_POST['how']);
    $subject  = check_input($_POST['subject'], "Add a subject");
    $comments = check_input($_POST['comments'], "Add your message");

    /* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
    {
            show_error("Email address is not valid");
    }

    /* If URL is not valid set $website to empty */
    if (!preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/+[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/i", $website))
    {
        $website = '';
    }

    /* Message for the email */
    $message = "Hello!

    Your contact form has been submitted by:

    Name: $yourname
    Email: $email
    Telephone: $telephone
    URL: $website

    Area of interest? $likeit
    How did they find us? $how_find

    Comments:
    $comments

    End of message
    ";

    /* Send the message using mail() function */
    mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

    /* Redirect visitor to the thankyou page */
    header('Location: thankyou.html');
    exit();

    /* Functions used */
    function check_input($data, $problem='')
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
        {
            show_error($problem);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function show_error($myError)
    {
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <!--
    Head data in here
    -->
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

        <body>

            <div id="mainheader">

    <div id="mainlogo">

    <h1><a href="http://www.X.co.uk/" title="X">
                                    <img style="border:0;width: 260px; height: 160px;" src="images/X.jpg" alt="X" /></a></h1>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
            <div class="content">
                    <h2 class="title">Error!</h2>

    <p><strong>Please correct the following error:</strong></p>
    <p><?php echo $myError; ?></p>

            </div>
    </div>

        <div id="panel">

            <div id="main" class="boxed">
                <h2 class="heading">Main</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="services" class="boxed">
                <h2 class="heading">Services</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="recent-projects.html">Recent projects</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="pricing" class="boxed">
                <h2 class="heading">Pricing</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="info" class="boxed">
                <h2 class="heading">Info</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="tips-and-tricks.html">Tips and tricks</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="useful-links.html">Useful links</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="faq.html">Frequently asked questions</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="site-map.html">Site map</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

                    <div id="contact" class="boxed">
                            <h2 class="heading">Contact</h2>
                            <ul>
                            <li><a href= "mailto:enquiries&#38;#64;X.co.uk">Contact by email</a> </li>
                            <li><strong>Telephone:<br />X</strong> </li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>

        </div>

       <div id="mainfooter">
                    <p> &#38;#169; 2011 X<br />Designed by <a href="http://www.X.co.uk/" title="X"><strong>X</strong></a> </p>
                            <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer" title="Valid XHTML 1.0">
                    <img style="border:0;width:88px;height:31px" src="images/valid-xhtml10.png" alt="Valid XHTML 1.0" />
                </a>
                            <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer" title="Valid CSS!">
                    <img style="border:0;width:88px;height:31px" src="images/vcss.gif" alt="Valid CSS!" />
                </a>
        </div>

        </body>
        </html>
    <?php
    exit();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: don't use a regular expression, to validate email address use the built in filter

Comment: @Dagon meh, that's a reasonably conservative filter; I'd rather use that than a filter I didn't understand that might try too hard and gave false negatives

Comment: well yours would fail many legit addresses as well -your call

Comment: @Dagon I'm not the questioner, just commenting; but yes, looking again, it is overly strict. Personally, I'd just simplify the regex though - replace `[\w\-]` with `[^@]` and it's pretty serviceable.

Comment: To somewhat answer your question, check out these links which may be of help: https://github.com/monodesigns/text-captcha and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041555/numeric-captcha-for-php

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally, the idea of captcha is to prevent automated form processing. Any non-image comparisons will be easily solved.

Regardless, I would use sessions to solve this issue.

Simply store the expected result in a session variable on the first page, and make sure it matches on the second

page1.php:

```
    <?php

    session_start();

    $digit1 = mt_rand(1,20);
    $digit2 = mt_rand(1,20);
    if( mt_rand(0,1) === 1 ) {
            $math = "$digit1 + $digit2";
            $_SESSION['answer'] = $digit1 + $digit2;
    } else {
            $math = "$digit1 - $digit2";
            $_SESSION['answer'] = $digit1 - $digit2;
    }

    ?>

    <form method="POST" action="page2.php">
            What's <?php echo $math; ?> = <input name="answer" type="text" /><br />
            <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

page2.php

```
    session_start();

    echo "You entered ".htmlentities($_POST['answer'])." which is ";

    if ($_SESSION['answer'] == $_POST['answer'] )
            echo 'correct';
    else
            echo 'wrong. We expected '.$_SESSION['answer'];

    ?>
```

Comment: Here is a simple [MathCaptcha](https://github.com/nettraction/Math_Captcha) class that may help

Answer (score 0):

Use a Simple PHP Math Captcha
https://github.com/kmlpandey77/MathCaptcha

## MathCaptcha

A Simple PHP Math Captcha

### Usage

```
composer require kmlpandey77/math-captcha
```

#### Math in Image

It will return Math in image

Create `captcha.php`

```php
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // link to vendor's autoload.php

use Kmlpandey77\MathCaptcha\Captcha;

$captcha = new Captcha();
$captcha->image();
```

Create `form.php`

```html
<form action="check.php" method="post">
    <p>
        Answer it <img src="./captcha.php" alt="" valign="middle">  <input type="text" name="captcha">
    </p>
    <p><button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button></p>
</form>
```

#### Math in Text

It will return Math in text

Create `form.php`

Place this code to top of `form.php`

```php
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // link to vendor's autoload.php

use Kmlpandey77\MathCaptcha\Captcha;
?>
```

And place this code in `body`

```html
<form action="check.php" method="post">
    <p>
        Answer it <?php echo new Captcha; ?>  <input type="text" name="captcha">
    </p>
    <p><button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button></p>
</form>
```

#### Check

Checks to see if the user entered the correct captcha key

Create `check.php`

```php
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // link to vendor's autoload.php
use Kmlpandey77\MathCaptcha\Captcha;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(Captcha::check()){

        //valid action

        echo('<font color="green">Answer is valid</font>');
    }else{
        echo('<font color="red">Answer is invalid</font>');
    }
}
```