# How do I pass a session variable correctly?

Tags: php, variables, session

I'm really new to PHP, and I'm trying to use the simple captcha mentioned in this question
[Numeric Captcha for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041555/numeric-captcha-for-php)

What I'm trying to do is pass the `$_SESSION['captcha']` to my current page, so it can compare with the input I just entered which is supposed to pass by the "form".

Here's my code:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['captcha'] ,$_SESSION['captcha'])) {
        if ($_POST['captcha'] == $_SESSION['captcha'])
            echo 'YES, YOU DID IT';
    }
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>captcha test</title>
</head>

<body>

<form name="input" action="index.php" method="POST">
<img src="captcha.php">
Enter the code above: <input type="text" name="captcha">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

What's the correct way to do this? How can I implement the captcha in my current code?

Comment: Why didn't you copy the complete example then?

Comment: @mario: I copied, the first part of the code is in the captcha.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things fixed here:

- First you did not use a `session_start()` to actually retrieve `$_SESSION` values. Added here.
- Next, you should check if the values are not empty by using `!empty()` in addition to `isset()`. Added here as well.
- Finally, I recommend you use `===` comparison operator instead of `==`. While `==` will check if values are the same, `===` will check if they are the same and the same data type.

Here is the cleaned up code:

```
<?php 

    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['captcha'], $_SESSION['captcha']) &&
        !empty($_POST['captcha']) && !empty($_SESSION['captcha'])) {
            if ($_POST['captcha'] === $_SESSION['captcha']) {
              echo 'YES, YOU DID IT';
            }
    }
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>captcha test</title>
</head>

<body>

<form name="input" action="index.php" method="POST">
<img src="captcha.php">
Enter the code above: <input type="text" name="captcha">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

If this still does not work for you, you can dump the values of `$_POST` and `$_SESSION` like this to see what you are getting:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: The `isset()` check is superfluous. `!empty($var)` is analogous to `isset($var) && $var` — you don't need both.

Comment: Thank you for your fix, but I still can't get the "YOU DID IT" msg printed on the screen. weird

Comment: @JakeGould: I think I found the problem, the $_SESSION array just won't change every time I enter a new value, how do I refresh its value to make it the same as the captcha value which is generated by the captcha.php.

Comment: @JakeGould: I accidentally removed "start_session()" in the beginning of the captcha.php, that caused the problem of $_SESSION is not refreshed, and another problem that I couldn't get the msg is because I used font that is different from the font the original author used, that caused one of the number in the numerical image had been cut off. that's why I couldn't get the right captcha value (always 1 digit short).  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add `session_start()` at the 1st line, thus the `$_SESSION` is empty.

Side Note:

- You mixed up XHTML and HTML. `xmlns` is not required for HTML.
- DOCTYPE is missing

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your session with

```
session_start();
```

as a first call before your script has any output.

See documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php