# ReCapcha Number Generator Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5, recaptcha, contact-form, laravel-blade

I want to Display a ReCapcha number image in Contact Form While submitting the form user must write the recapcha code in given field...I need to know that how can i generate these randon numbers...

Here is html for input field and img..

```
 <img src="" alt="This Is a CAPTCHA Image"><br>
 Enter the text of the image above <br>
<input name="strCaptcha" type="text" size="8" value="" maxlength="8">
```

Below Picture is an example for recapcha.Please review and tell me how i can do this..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have many libraries.

1.Captcha for Laravel 5

https://github.com/mewebstudio/captcha

To install Require this package with composer:

```
composer require mews/captcha
```

2.no-captcha (its an google captcha)

https://github.com/anhskohbo/no-captcha

To install Require this package with composer:

```
composer require anhskohbo/no-captcha
```

if you are looking for developing your own then you can

```
session_start();

$strings = '123456789';
$i = 0;
$characters = 6;
$code = '';
while ($i < $characters)
{ 
    $code .= substr($strings, mt_rand(0, strlen($strings)-1), 1);
    $i++;
} 

$_SESSION['captcha'] = $code;

//generate image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(124, 40);
$foreground = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$shadow = imagecolorallocate($im, 173, 172, 168);
$background = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 200, 200, $background);

// use your own font!
$font = 'monofont.ttf';

//draw text:
imagettftext($im, 35, 0, 9, 28, $shadow, $font, $code);
imagettftext($im, 35, 0, 2, 32, $foreground, $font, $code);     

// prevent client side  caching
header("Expires: Wed, 1 Jan 1997 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

//send image to browser
header ("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Display it in a form:

```
<img src="captcha.php">
```

Enter the code above: `<input type="text" name="captcha">`
Once submitted, check the entered code:

```
if ($_POST['captcha'] == $_SESSION['captcha'])
```

Re:
[Numeric Captcha for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041555/numeric-captcha-for-php)

Answer (score 0):

I made one with about 10 lines and the GD library.

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

It's really easy. I generate an image and with img src serve it to the user. I am transferring the solution via $_SESSION. Here are some tips to make it more secure.

1. Rotate the text randomly
2. Add random spaces in between characters
3. Use a TTF fonts and change the font randomly every time
4. Use a random text and image size every time
5. Use more advanced text distortion and colors
6. Move the lines randomly
7. Store the password in a random cookie

P.S.: The key is to make the text and distortion the same color so the bot can get confused what symbol are you displaying.

Advice: Don't use a ready library because there can be a vulnerability. Also the uniqueness of the code is better than using somebody else's solution for security. We all use Google after all.

Optional: For user comfort - don't use o, O, Q and 0.